# Loosen/disable password policy

Tags: password

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how to loosen or disable the strong password policy?
Would like to do it without the use of a plugin.
I'm running a non-public site and don't need strong security.
[image]

Comment: There is no "strong password policy" in wordpress

Comment: Well, you cannot make a simple password, it will only accept very strong passwords, when you create an account as a user.
Maybe "policy" is not the right word.
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/28/passwords-strong-by-default/

Comment: Unless something have changed while I wasn't paying attention, you can confirm a weak password if you want to use one. It is not impossible, just requires additional click.

Comment: It's not when creating the admin account or creating user-account in the backend.
It's when a user creates his own account in the frontend. In my case using the e-commerce plugin WooCoomerce. But as far I can read this strong password policy is a WP core feature, not delivered by the plugin. But I find it VERY restrictive and I want to disable it or loosen it.
I've added a screen-dump to my question.

Comment: woocomerce has probably nothing to do with password policy, it is something you installed/configured specifically for that.

Comment: it's a WP core service. They implemented the library called "zxcvbn", made by Dropbox in 2012.

Comment: if it is WC that implemented it that way, then you have to ask for support in their support forums

Comment: I already did....but I have more faith in wordpress.stackexchange ;-)

Answer (score 13):

This will do it :-)

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'DisableStrongPW', 100 );

function DisableStrongPW() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
    }
}
```

I found the solution [here](https://nicolamustone.com/2016/01/27/remove-the-password-strength-meter-on-the-checkout-page/).

Comment: This did not work for me. I even tried changing it to `'password-strength-meter'`

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's not possible to change the strength requirements of the password. 
You can only deactivate it the functionality completely by dequeueing the password script:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'DisableStrongPW', 100 );

function DisableStrongPW() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'user-profile', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'user-profile' );
    }
}
```

For changing the minimum strength of the password I can recommend this plugin which builds on the same library and integrates nicely into woocommerce:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-password-strength-settings/

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this answer:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'DisableStrongPW', 100 );

function DisableStrongPW() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'user-profile', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'user-profile' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did anything change? New WP version? Haven't played with WP for some time now.

Answer (score -1):

It can also be set in the wp_generate_password function. Just in case you use it for your own code. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_password

Comment: This only changes the default suggested password, it doesn't change the minimum strength required of the chosen password.